# Importing CSV (downloaded from Google Drive) with polygonal geometry data, into QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, geometry, csv, google-fusion-tables

I formerly used Google Fusion Tables but due to the product downturn I had to bulk-download a backup copy of my data. Right now I have them all saved in CSV format.

I have attribute columns in these tables but also a column simply named as "geometry" all bunched up together, in a single column.

It's in the format of `<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>[coord],[coord],[coord] [coord],[coord],[coord] [coord],[coord],[coord]</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>` where `[coord]` is something like `-129.83` for instance.

I'm trying to import this data into QGIS 3 and I've tried it both as a vector layer as well as delimited text file format. However, nothing actually shows up on the map.

What can I do to resolve this situation?

Comment: rename .csv to .kml? then load into qgis

Comment: @Mapperz this is even worse, it won't even let me upload now

Comment: not sure what your are meaning 'upload' - the format you describe is kml > https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#polygons

Comment: Well idk, but the only error it gives me is "Invalid data source: [...]/file.kml is not a recognized or valid data source." Same thing happens if I try zipping it up into a KMZ

Comment: @Mapperz Could you help me out here please?

Comment: I guess if you provided some sample data, it would be easier to help you. Did you try to open the data in any other application, like google earth, and export it from there?